# How can I list all files in a Linux directory that holds basic commands and shells used by root and other users using a full path?

Tags: linux, unix, opensuse

I know I'll be using the command `ls` but I don't know what holds the basic commands and shells used by root and other users using the full path.

Comment: elaborate your question please.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard, Linux has 4 main locations for binaries and shell scripts:

- `/bin` - essential commands which must be available for all users (including in single-user mode)
- `/sbin` - essential system commands which must be available to root or other admins (including in
  single-user mode)
- `/usr/bin` - non-essential commands (not required in single-user mode) for all users
- `/usr/sbin` - non-essential system commands (not required in single-user mode) for root or other admins

By the wording of your question, I'd guess that whoever originated the question was indicating that they want a listing of `/bin`, which "contains basic commands and shells used by root and other users."

Your list should therefore start out something like this:

```
/bin/arch
/bin/awk
/bin/basename
/bin/bash
/bin/cat
/bin/cgclassify
/bin/cgcreate
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ls command  and include some options to find out the time of creation,memory size tc on ur command prompt.

```
ls -ltr
```

Check this link for more options http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uls.htm